# Play 2.3/Angular JS $resource/routing issue

Tags: angularjs, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0, angularjs-routing

So I'm trying to AJAX a single solr doc from my results list to a "doc view" view. I'm trying to use AngularJS to AJAX to my view render method and display the doc that way, but I can't seem to get the angular to work and I'm not sure I'm doing things correctly on the Play side either. Would you at least be willing to tell me if what I'm trying to do will work? The Angular error comes from the docText.text(); call. Here is my code:

Angular controller code:

```
    var docText = $resource("http://localhost:9000/views/full-doc-text.html", {
        text: {method: 'PUT'}
    });

    $scope.handleViewText = function(value) {
        docText.text({doc: value});
    }
```

Java code:

```
    public static Result viewText() {
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

        //do stuff here

        return ok(viewtext.render(json));
    }
```

route:

```
    GET     /views/full-doc-text.html            controllers.Application.viewText()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see three problems with the code above;

1.The definition of `docText` resource is not correct. if your read the angularjs manual [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) you'll see that `$resource` has 4 parameters. First one is resource url, second is parameter defaults, third one is custom actions and forth one is resource options where last three of them are optional. In your code you pass custom actions as the second parameter, which should be the third. And since you don't have any parameters in your resource url second parameter must be null. So first correction is:

```
var docText = $resource("http://localhost:9000/views/full-doc-text.html", null, {
    text: {method: 'PUT'}
});
```

2.You define your `text` action's HTTP method as `PUT` however in your routes file you are handling `GET` requests for your desired action. You should change your route definition as:

```
PUT     /views/full-doc-text.html            controllers.Application.viewText()
```

3.`PUT` method is usually used for update operations when implementing a RESTFULL service. In your case you don't seem to be updating anything. So I suggest to use `POST` method just for convention.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about some of the lazy code (mainly the routing which is/was fixed in my route file, I just didn't make the correction here, also the PUT was there because I was just trying things after POST failed).

Comment: Looking at it though, the route /views/full-doc-text.html should be a GET call as it is going to serve up the full-doc-text.html page to the client side, so should I have a "catch" POST method to catch the post call, process anything on the JSON and then call the GET method to serve the full-doc-text page?

Comment: sorry but i'm unable to figure out your use case. what i could figure out from your code above is that; you are submitting some json data to backend, manipulating it and then rendering it. in this scenario /views/full-doc-text.html route needs to correspond to a HTTP method with body (PUT or POST). GET method wouldn't be sensible since you are submitting data  with $scope.handleViewText. If you can clarify your use case i may suggest some solution. good luck ;)

Comment: Yeah, after taking the weekend and coming back to look at it, I've got no idea what I'm trying to do. I shouldn't code while frustrated because then this happens. You're right, I'm wrong and I was thinking incorrectly. Thanks for helping me correct my resource method though.